Adding 2 cameras - Front and Rear in a car


I want to install 2 cameras: Rear camera and Front camera.
The rear camera will be activated only when the REVERSE light is ON.
And, the front camera will be activated only when the Switch button is pressed.
Only ONE camera is to be activated at one time i.e. either the rear or the front.
There is ONE RCA FEMALE Green PORT at the back of the Android Unit.
So, I will employ a common RCA male connector joined to the pin 30 of the DPDT +12V relay as attached photo here. Both relays are +12V DC.
I have attached the corresponding diagram which I presumed will serve these two features.
And, one more confusion, is the YELLOW RCA connector 1 wire or 2 wires? If 2 wires, what is the purpose of the second wire?
I assume that the YELLOW connector of the camera is only 1 wire which transfers the video signal/information to the Android unit.
Red RCA connector has 2 wires : One is +12V input and another is Ground wire.
Yellow RCA connector has 1 wire (assuming).
So, total 3 wires.
So, please enlighten for any correction/suggestions on my diagram, and also waiting the answer to the confusion on the YELLOW RCA connector.
Thanks.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
